# How to configure sourceMaps for LESS using Grunt when there is more than one file in your project?

Tags: less, gruntjs, source-maps

I have multiple .less files that I want processed to their matching .css with sourceMaps for each file all in the same folder as the source.

How hard can that be?

I have no problem in doing this directly with less but cant figure out how to do this in grunt-contrib-less as it seems to want the sourceMapFilename to be a single hard coded value.

This my gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
pkg: grunt.file.readJSON("package.json"),
watch: {
  options: {
    livereload: true,
  },
  css: {
    files: ['./core/theme/**/*.less'],
    tasks: ['less'],
    options: {
      spawn: false
    },
  },
},
less: {
  all: {
    src: ['./core/theme/**/*.less'],
    expand: true,  
    dest: "./core/theme/",
    options:{sourceMap:true},
rename:function (dest, src) {
        return src.substring(0, src.lastIndexOf('.'))+'.css';
    }
  },
}   
});
// on watch events configure less:all to only run on changed file
grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath) {
  grunt.config('less.all.src', filepath);
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-watch");
grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-less");

grunt.registerTask("default", ["less"]);
};
```

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You could define multiple targets. Each target compiles a specific less file.
Assuming that you have a reasonable/limited list of less files to compile (< 10?).
http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets

Define common task-level options (less compile options), then target specific options (sourceMapFilename & sourceMapURL).
http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#options

I'm not sure how to set the sourceMapFilename dynamically, but I will look into this later. It would be necessary if you were compiling many LESS files (> 10?).

Comment: Unfortunately I have 20+ files and in any case this would then require 20+ watchers each watching one file which seems a huge waste of resources.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. I have hunddreds of less files in my use case. Let us know if you find a solution.

Comment: AFAIK, multiple targets is *the only* way for the moment. I suppose this (automatic target generation) can be automated in Grunt so with certain tricks it should be possible to get things more simple than hardcoding all 100 targets manually.

Answer (score 0):

Currently grunt-contrib-less has not got such an option, see: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less/issues/89

You can use [grunt.file](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file) to get a list of your less files and than automatically generate your task per file, see also: [Compile LESS to multiple CSS files, based on variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26751574/compile-less-to-multiple-css-files-based-on-variable-value/26752074)

**Gruntfile.js:**

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  'use strict';
grunt.initConfig({
      pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
});

var allTaskArray = [];
var tasks = {};

grunt.file.recurse('less/', function(abspath, rootdir, subdir, filename)
{
    if(filename.match(/\.less$/g)){
        var name = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
        tasks[name] = {options: {sourceMap:true},files:{} };
        tasks[name]['options']['sourceMapFilename'] = 'dist/' + name + '.map.css';
        tasks[name]['files']['dist/' + name + '.css'] = abspath;
        allTaskArray.push('less:' + name);
    }

});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
grunt.config('less',tasks);
grunt.registerTask( 'default', allTaskArray );  
};
```

When you file structure looks like that shown below:

```
less
├── less2
│   └── main2.less
└── main.less
```

running `grunt` will result in:

```
Running "less:main2" (less) task
File dist/main2.map.css created.
File dist/main2.css created: 24 B → 66 B

Running "less:main" (less) task
File dist/main.map.css created.
File dist/main.css created: 24 B → 65 B
```

Notice that you can also add dynamically your watch task as follows:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
var watch = {
  options: {
    livereload: true,
  },
  css: {
    files: ['./less/**/*.less'],
    tasks: [],
    options: {
      spawn: false
    },
  }
};
watch['css']['tasks'] = allTaskArray;
grunt.config('watch',watch);
```